# Save and Restore an object to database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Lets say i have an object with this format:

```
   public class ObjectClassSample
    {
        public string product { set; get; }
        public string Description { set; get; }
        public int Price { set; get; } 
    }
```

Im trying to same this object inside a string field in a record in my database. is it possible to this without converting this to JSON, as i was thinking what is the best way to save and restore this.

Comment: Anyway you will have to serialize your class. If not JSON, then XML

Answer (score 1):

One way or another you have to convert that object to a string, I'm unsure why you don't want to use JSON, but to do it without converting to JSON, you could make your own **error prone** format.

Here is an example of just converting the object to a string, separating each property by a comma.

Some Extension Methods

```
public static class ObjectSampleExtensions
{
    public static ObjectClassSample ToObjectClassSample(this string s)
    {
        var parts = s.Split(new [] { ','});
        return new ObjectClassSample 
        {
              product = parts[0],
              Description = parts[1],
              Price = int.Parse(parts[2])
        };
    }

    public static string ConvertToString(this ObjectClassSample objectToConvertToString)
    {
        const string delimiter = ",";
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(objectToConvertToString.product);
        sb.Append(delimiter);
        sb.Append(objectToConvertToString.Description);
        sb.Append(delimiter);
        sb.Append(objectToConvertToString.Price);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then Usage

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = new ObjectClassSample 
    {
        Description = "this is the description",
        Price = 3,
        product = "my product"
    };

    var s = obj.ConvertToString();

    //you can now save s to the database
    Db.Save(s);

    //later on pretend you read 's' back from the database
    s = Db.ReadAnItem();
    var objectFromDb = s.ToObjectClassSample();
}
```

So yeah, you can serialize the data anyway you want, but I would use a common format: json, xml, csv, whatever.

I wouldn't recommend using the code above, that was just an example to show you can basically do whatever you want to convert it to a string, so long as you can convert it back.  Using a json parser would be much easier though.

An example with ServiceStack.Text would look like this

```
var objToSerialize = new ObjectClassSample(); //fill this with data
string myObjectAsString = objToSerialize.ToJson();

//reading it back from the database

ObjectClassSample myObj = myObjectAsString.FromJson<ObjectClassSample>();
```

I'm sure newstonsoft.json is similar.

As you can see...much prettier.